# How to aggregate new document from Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MonoDB showing incomes. It has _id, name, and income documents. I want to write a query the returns name and a new document call AverageIncome that reads "true" in income < 40,000 and false otherwise. I tried the following code.

```
db.collection.aggregrate([{income:{$exists:true}}, {$project:{income:1, Averageincome: {$cond:{if;{$gte:{$'income', 40000]}, then: true, else:false}}}}])
```

I get an output but it is far in excess of what I need. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define within the `$match` stage your first step. Since the `$gte` operator returns `true|false`, you don't need to add the `$cond` operator.

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      income: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name:1,
      income: 1,
      Averageincome: {
        $gte: [
          "$income",
          40000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ohNL-jP2KUl)

Comment: Hi, The code works but it doesn't return the name of who receives the average income. I've tried to figure it out, is it possible I should be using find??

Comment: @Peadar08 Check it again, we just need to include the `name` field.

Comment: I've tried this but got an error  db.docs.find({income:{$exists:true}}, {_id:0, name:1, level:1}, {AveIncome:{$cond:{if:{$gte:[$'income', 40000]}}, then: true, else:false }})  The error is E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list :

Comment: @Peadar08 You can't run do it with `.find` method, it should be `.aggregate`

Comment: Thank you. I just released that. I'm going with aggregate but can't see why the following wont work       db.docs.aggregate({[$match:{income:{$exists:true}}, {_id:0, name:1}, {AveIncome:{$cond:{if:{$income:{$gt: 40000}}}, then: true, else:false }}}])